# How to include a .properties file in i18n.properties file on SAPUI5?

Tags: internationalization, sapui5, properties-file

### Environement

Framework: SAPUI5 V1.38.39

### Issue

Well, the issue may semble stupid but is it as follow :
I have an application with a lot of text, which makes very huge i18n files, that why I wanted to separate them into several files for the files to be cleaner. For example :

- an i18n.properties including i18n_food.properties, i18n_ingredient.properties, etc.
- an i18n_en.properties including i18n_food_en.properties, i18n_ingredient_en.properties, etc.
- an i18n_de.properties including i18n_food_de.properties, i18n_ingredient_de.properties, etc.
- an i18n_fr.properties including i18n_food_fr.properties, i18n_ingredient_fr.properties, etc.

### Attemps

What I try is to make as for [Apache .properties files](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html) meaning :

```
#i18n.properties
include = i18n_food.properties
```

```
#i18n_food.properties
recipeSelection = A selection of recipe
recipeDetail = Recipe details
```

But it doesn't work, in the view, I bind with "{i18n>recipeDetail}" and instead of showing "Recipe details" it shows "recipeDetail"

Comment: `_food` is not a valid locale. It expects a suffix, which describes the locale, for example `_de` for German. Read more here https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f225ce6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070

Comment: @PetarD. sorry but the question is not how to switch language it is how to include another .properties file in a properties file for having several .propeties file (for example 1 per page) instead of having 1 .properties file making several thousands lines

Answer (score 0):

Check you manifest file, whether you have updated your new i18n file name

```
"models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "xxxx.xxxx.i18n.i18n",
                "bundleName": "xxxx.xxxx.i18n.i18n_food"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply @santhosh, I just tries but it doesn't work, none of the i18n files works then. I seen also in documentation enhanceWith should I define it ?

Comment: @SylwekFr `enhanceWith` is not available in 1.38.x. I'd like to strongly suggest, again, to upgrade your UI5 version as the support will end this year and to benefit from current improvements as well as security fixes. UI5 is backwards compatible.

Comment: Hello @BoghyonHoffmann, thank you again for your reply, unfortunately I cannot change the version

Comment: @SylwekFr I know it's not that simple :P just wanted to emphasize again, how important that is